# Given Value is not rendering in Razor input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Solved**: had to remove the layout from the partial.

I have the following input:

```
@Html.Hidden("VendorId", (string)ViewBag.VendorId)
```

which doesn't render the value from the `ViewBag`, so, after trying everything I knew in this situation (even using the html instead of razor, still the value remains null), I figured it  would be about time to try solving this with `jQuery`, but things keep getting stranger. The following doesn't work:

```
$("#VendorId").val(id);
$("#VendorId : input").val(id);
```

but this works even doe jquery has at least one syntax error because of it:

```
$("#VendorId : input").val() = id;
$("VendorId : input").val() = id;
```

So, my question is, is it just me or this is really wrong? And if it is wrong, can anyone think of any reason why this is happening? I'm guessing the behaviour of razor and jquery are connected somehow but can't figure it out so I need a bit of help with this. Pretty sure it's something obvious.

I am using `jQuery 1.10.2`

This is where i set up the value for the `ViewBag`:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> SelectvendorList(string VendorId)
{
    ViewBag.VendorName = await _vendorService.GetVendorName(VendorId);
    if (VendorId == null) VendorId = "";
    ViewBag.VendorId = VendorId;

    var lists = await _vendorListService.GetAllForSelectList(User.Identity.GetUserId(), VendorId);

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> vendorLists = lists.Select(b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.Id, Text = b.Description });
    ViewBag.vendorLists = vendorLists;

    return PartialView();
}
```

I also have this paragraph in my view and it renders the value corectly:

```
<p id="hiddenVendorId" style="display:none">@vendorId</p>
```

Here is the entire view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SelectvendorList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Purchasing.cshtml";
    var vendorId = ViewBag.VendorId;
}

<p>New Order / Select vendor list</p>

<h4>Vendor : @ViewBag.VendorName</h4>
<p id="hiddenVendorId" style="display:none">@ViewBag.VendorId</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRemoveItems", "Order", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Hidden("VendorId", (string)ViewBag.VendorId)
    <div class="form-group flex">
        @Html.Label("VendorListID", "Vendor Lists", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="">
            @Html.DropDownList("VendorListID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.vendorLists, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("VendorListID", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    <input type="button" id="backButton" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" value="Back" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Continue with no Vendor List", "AddRemoveItems", new { VendorId = vendorId, VendorListID = "" })
}
```

Comment: Are you definitely setting `ViewBag.SomeValue` in your controller method?

Comment: `@Html.Hidden("VendorId", (string)ViewBag.SomeValue)` will generate a hidden input with `value="xxx"` where `ViewBag.SomeValue = "xxx"` You do not need any scripts.

Comment: But why not just set the value of `model.VendorId` in the controller and just use `@Html.Hidden("VendorId")` or better `@Html.HiddenFor(m => VendorId)`?

Comment: Can you show us where do you set the value of your `Id`? It's problably the root of all evil

Comment: I know, that's what I was going for, but, I have this paragraph as well just to see if the `ViewBag` is set: `<p id="hiddenVendorId" style="display:none">@vendorId</p>` and the text inside this paragraph is indeed the value of the `ViewBag` but the razor code still doesn't render it, I know it will be hidden, that is the point since the value is an Id.

Comment: `@vendorId` is not the same as `ViewBag.SomeValue`.

Comment: Re your edit - `ViewBag.SomeValue` is not the same as `@vendorId`

Comment: I know, When I first wrote this post I wrote it in a more general way, I edited it as it actually is, it's VendorId everywhere.

Comment: What is the point of `if (VendorId == null) VendorId = "";`? And you may as well use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => VendorId)`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke The point is that VendorId is being passed from another view, I will post that view in a sec. Also, didn't wanted to set up a model for a simple string. That's why I was using ViewBag.

Comment: "_didn't wanted to set up a model for a simple string_" - Look at all the time you've saved!

Comment: If you want to use bad practice, then fine, but the fact is that if `ViewBag.VendorId` has a value, then that value **will** be rendered in the `value` attribute of the hidden input using `@Html.Hidden("VendorId", (string)ViewBag.VendorId)`

Comment: @ChrisPickford Yes Chris, you are right, but this may not be a bad thing if I can fix this bug, if not, it might screw something else later.. so at least I got to discover it... I guess :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Yes, that's what it should happen, but as I said before, it's not happening here.

Comment: Then its due to code you have not shown us.

Comment: @Spluf - is it possible we're not seeing the right controller here?  You're returning a partial view, and if I'm not mistaken - the view you posted is NOT a partial view.

Comment: Well, then it doesn't make sense that your paragraph tag is working.  This is odd.  I had no problem.  Have you set a breakpoint in your controller?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky Thx man for this, you can post it as an answer so I can vote it, this was the problem, it al works well now (either by removing the layout from the view or by returning a view from the controller). So, you fixed it :),

Comment: Glad I can help - unfortunately I'm not able to post it as an answer because I really can't explain **why** it was happening.  Again, glad we worked you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that

```
<p id="hiddenVendorId" style="display:none">@vendorId</p>
```

renders the correct value, you could consider using the same variable in your hidden input, instead of the `ViewBag`:

```
@Html.Hidden("VendorId", vendorId)
```

Comment: I tried, not working, makes no sense... but if i replace @vendorId with the viewbag in the paragraph it's still working fine there..

Comment: Add your controller method to the question, as well as any interactions you have with the variable in your view.

Comment: So what you're saying is that somewhere between displaying the value of the same variable in two different places it's somehow becoming `null`?

Comment: I posted the entire view now, there's nothing deleting the value from the ViewBag there, and still, in the same view the value is both rendered and ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move away from using the `ViewBag` dynamic object to pass information to your views and instead create a simple `ViewModel`. E.g.

```
public class VendorViewModel
{
   public string VendorId {get; set;}
   public string VendorName {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VendorList {get; set;}
}
```

In your view, at the top define the model in use

```
@model VendorViewModel
```

Then to render your hidden input:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(v => v.VendorId)
```

Answer (score -1):

To give alue and id to input in razor, do like following

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.VendorId, new{ @Value = ViewBag.SomeValue}, new {@id ="VendorId"})
```

Consider `ViewBag.SomeValue` has value "vendor"
This will render a html input tag like

```
<input type="text" value="vendor" id="VendorId" name="VendorId">
```

In javascript
To get the input value

```
$("#VendorId").val();
```

To assign a value to the input field

```
var id = "VendorId";
$("#VendorId").val(id);
```

hope this helps

Comment: this looks like a combination of all the things that should work (and I already tried) but still doesn't :). Thanks for trying anyway :)